# ¿ SUMA DE COLUMNAS DE DIFERENTES TABLAS POR MYSQL?

Tags: sql

soy nuevo en esto, y me pidieron hacer una actividad con mysql, tengo una base de datos pequeña con dos tablas donde una tiene informacion de clientes, nombre apellido, telefono, direc, y el dinero a prestar, y tengo otra tabla que tiene solo 3 columnas, id(del cliente que paga) el abono, y la fecha, el tema esta en que cuando hago la consulta para sumar los prestamos, y los abonos, me sale la consulta bien pero los valores son errados. y desconozco cual seria el erro, pls su ayuda.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ese sql tiene tantos problemas... deberias leer sobre group by, sobre join.. a tu consutla le falta todo eso... por eso pensas que te trae cosas que estan mal.. en realidad lo que devuelve es un producto cartesiano de la suma de todas las filas.. que no es lo que vos queres...

Comment: ah.. y porque decis que no estan relacionadas? si una tiene el id del cliente y la de cliente seguro tiene un id tambien? donde es que no estan relacionadas?

Comment: Mis disculpas, ambas si estan relacionada por ID, mi error es que la consulta no me trae los datos como deben ser.

Comment: sabes sobre group by y sobre inner join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos y bienvenido a SO! te recomiendo revisar los links que te enviaron en los comentarios, allí se explica como preparar una pregunta con la información necesaria para que te puedan ayudar.

Volviendo a tu pregunta, tu consulta tiene dos problemas principales:

- Estas uniendo dos tablas sin indicar cual campo es el que las relaciona: si no colocas el/los campos de la relación en una clausula `JOIN`, MySQL va a usar todas las combinaciones posibles (los montos serán incorrectos).
- Si vas a usar una función de agrupamiento (`SUM()`) normalmente necesitas también usar la clausula `GROUP BY`: si no la usas, te dará un total global, en tu caso creo que la necesitas, para obtener el total de cada cliente.

Prueba cambiando la consulta así:

```
SELECT clientes.id, 
       clientes.prestamo, 
       SUM(prestamos.abono) total_abono
FROM prestamos
JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = prestamos.id
GROUP BY clientes.id, clientes.prestamo
```

Cambios:

- Se incluye el id del cliente: verás los prestamos y abonos por cliente
- En el `FROM` solo se coloca una tabla, la segunda se agrega con un `JOIN` indicando los campos de relación.
- En el `GROUP BY` debes colocar los campos que no estén en funciones de agrupamiento.
- Sugerencia: prueba cambiando `JOIN` por `LEFT JOIN` para incluir los clientes que no hayan hecho ningún abono.

*(NOTA: yo trabajo con SQL Server, no MySQL, aunque creo que esta sintaxis que es idéntica)*

Comment: Muchas gracias, una gran respuesta

Comment: De nada! Toma en cuenta también lo que comentó David: el saldo del cliente debería actualizarse cuando se agrega un abono. Recuerda marcar una respuesta como correcta una vez que hayas resuelto, para que tu pregunta se marque como "contestada".

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué tal si vamos un paso más allá y actualizamos ese campo calculado de `saldo` que tienes tan desactualizado?

```
UPDATE cliente JOIN (
    SELECT id,SUM(abono) abonos
      FROM prestamos
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(id)
  set saldo=prestamo-abonos;
```

A partir de este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente(
  id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31),
  prestamo float,
  saldo float,
  fecha date
  );
CREATE TABLE prestamos(
  id_apunte int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id int,
  abono float,
  fecha date,
  FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES cliente(id)
  );
INSERT INTO cliente (id, nombre, prestamo, fecha) VALUES
  (1005,'Jair',24000,NOW());
INSERT INTO prestamos (id, abono, fecha) VALUES
  (1005,2000,NOW()),
  (1005,1500,NOW());
```

Obtendrías:

```
+------+--------+----------+-------+------------+
| id   | nombre | prestamo | saldo | fecha      |
+------+--------+----------+-------+------------+
| 1005 | Jair   |    24000 | 20500 | 2022-08-21 |
+------+--------+----------+-------+------------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, una gran respuesta